# I want to simply make a object that connects to the mysql database with zendframework2

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've read the zend framework2 site about the database but I still dont get it.
Well, for example, to connect to the database with pdo is simple. you can make a 
object of the pdo and use it it any where , but how do you exactly make a the object 
to connect to the database with zf2?

//how do you use this script? Can you use it in a function ?

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

Comment: That looks like zf1 not zf2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're starting from scratch. Let me show you how I setup my database connections. Hope this helps:

First, go to your `project/config/autoload/global.php` file and add the `AdapterAbstractServiceFactory` like below:

### global.php

```
return  array(
    'module_layouts'    =>  array(...),
    'service_manager'   =>  array(
        'abstract_factories'    =>  array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
            ),
        'factories'=>  array(
            ),
        ),
    'session_config' =>  array(...),
    );
```

Second, go to your `project/config/autoload` folder and either create or edit the local.php file. (Note: rename the `local.dist.php` file if you have that). It should look like this (for now)

### local.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
       'adapters' => array(
         // Main database
         'main-db' => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo',
            'dsn'       => 'mysql:dbname=dbname1;host=localhost',
            'username'  => 'username',
            'password'  => 'password',
            ),
         // Another Database
         'anthr-db' => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo',
            'dsn'       => 'mysql:dbname=dbname2;host=localhost',
            'username'  => 'username',
            'password'  => 'password',
            ),
         )
       ),
    );
```

Third, make sure your database is up and running and it is possible to connect to it from the command line

Fourth, ... an object doesn't really connect to the database. I'm assuming you're talking about mapping objects to the data in your database, manipulating your data, etc. You're going to have to read [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html) and take the time to understand it. Once you do, this is pretty much a one and done deal and going up to issues like Doctrine 2 will be much easier...I mean less of a headache